# Firebase, how do I catch a exception and tell the user about it?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, exception, firebase-authentication

```dart
Future<Users?>createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, 
      password: password 
    ); 
    return _userFromFirebase(credential.user); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception with a `try/catch` and show it on the UI in a number of ways. Example

```
Future<Users?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    String email,
    String password,
  ) async {
    try {
      final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      return _userFromFirebase(credential.user);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // FirebaseException
      print(e.message);
    } catch (e) {
      // all other exceptions
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: swedischeef thnks in loginPage onPressed button it Worked                                   onPressed: () async {
if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
try{
await authService.signInWithEmailPassword(
emailController.text,
passwordController.text
);
Navigator.pop(context); }catch(e){
await showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext) =>
AlertDialog(
title: Text('ERROR'),
content: Text(e.toString()),
actions: <Widget>[
TextButton(
child: Text('Ok'),
onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
)],) );} }}

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. Mind accepting my answer?